# SQL MULTY QUERY

Tags: sql

I have **two tables**, clients and subscriptions. We can find **many subscriptions in the table of subscriptions from a client**. It is **allied by a foreign key(client_id)**.

**In the table subscriptions I have a parameter status**, the values could be "active, start pending, cancelled..."

**I want to get all the clients**(SELECT * FROM clients), but **I want to add  new column in the query(STATUS_CLIENT)**: this column must be true if I find an status='active' in one of the subscriptions of the client and false if I dont get any active status in the table subscriptions.

Thanks!

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this problem?

Comment: This question does not show any research-effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please specify which DBMS you are using. Each DBMS has its own feature set and its own SQL dialect. For example, MS SQL Server does not have an actual boolean data type, while PostgreSQL does.

The actual solution could be to add an additional column, which contains a correlated subquery for table `subscriptions`. Something like this:

```
SELECT
  C.*,
  EXISTS (SELECT *
          FROM subscriptions
          WHERE client_id = C.client_id AND status = 'active') AS status_client
FROM
  clients C
```

Depending on the DBMS you use, you might need to tweak this conceptual query. If you need additional help, please first specify the actual DBMS or SQL dialect in your question.